# How much RAM is required for model inferencing?

Tags: llm, llama-2, api, genai-ecosystem, conversational-ai

When I run `ollama run mistral:text`, I see a model of around 4GiB pulled.

1. Is this 4GiB model the GGUF or GGML file?
2. Once pulled, I see the ready prompt. At that point, is whole of the model loaded into memory?
3. If yes, how does one co-relate the model size and RAM requirements for inferencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. GGUF = new file format aiming at replacing GGML.
2. Yes.
3. (V)RAM requirement for inference: [Model size < RAM requirements < Model size * 1.2](https://blog.eleuther.ai/transformer-math/).

https://huggingface.co/spaces/hf-accelerate/model-memory-usage is helpful, e.g.:

[image]